# How do I use a Script reference tag in a SharePoint VisualWebPart

Tags: sharepoint-2010, web-parts

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I want to use the above ScriptTag in a SharePoint Visual webpart; any ideas on how I can achieve this?

As it is, the jQuery does not get triggered.

I am fairly new to SharePoint VisualWebParts.

Comment: What do you mean by does not get triggered ?

Comment: @MadhurAhuja it is not loaded on the page, I checked using Mozilla FireBug & I set an alert as well incase I misread the FireBug Script

Comment: This can be closed under the official close reason: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A script tag in the masterpage was overriding the one on the page this was on.